# How to tell if a system process is probing/grabbing bluetooth device?

Tags: bluetooth

I'm using a home automation platform called HomeAssistant to do presence detection via bluetooth. This works fine for a little while but at some point the detection will fail with a message that the device (hci0) must be reset. Indeed, if I issue sudo hciconfig hci0 reset then restart HomeAssistant it will start working again. It seems that some system service is probing/grabbing the bluetooth device periodically (could be minutes to hours but always eventually) resulting in the inability to detect.

I don't really have any idea how to determine if/which process might be taking control of the bluetooth device and how to prevent that from happening so that HomeAssistant can control the device always.

Any thoughts?

Comment: It could also mean that the Bluetooth chip is flaky, or that the Bluetooth kernel module has a bug that causes drops. Seen those before, too. Note the *exact* time of an error message, then check /var/log/syslog and dmesg for a few minutes leading up to the error.

Comment: Finally was able to catch a failure and check syslog. Sadly no messages in the vicinity of the fail time. Is there a config file somewhere to check for possible calls/uses that might be probing?

Comment: Anyone have a comment here? Seems like a fairly common problem. Cam across "coexistence mode" which others said interefered with bluetooth when wifi turns on - disabled that mode but still happening.

Comment: Not sure why you seem to believe some-other-process is seizing control of BT.  While possible, it's by far the least likely possibility. Ordinary buggy driver that needs to be reset with a cron job seems the most likely. Look up how to use `lsof` for next time BT fails. If something is connecting to BT, lsof is likely to reveal it...but learn it ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea whatsoever is going on. It's going to be tough to catch the device just as it becomes un-pingable by my presence detection system, I guess "lsof could tell me if there is indeed a process with the device file open? Is there any specific bluetooth log that could be set to debug and captured? As I said, syslog didn't show anything nor did dmesg. Seems crazy to just run a chron job to reset the device every few seconds. That's how often I'd like to be able to detect, but the system seems to only go offline every few hours.

Comment: Step back a second: BT has it's own daemon (bluez). The daemon talks to the driver. Applications talk to the daemon, NOT the driver directly. The whole stack is specifically designed to prevent applications fighting over BT. That's why I say it's "by far the least likely possibility"  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37003147/i-want-to-enable-debug-messages-on-bluez for how to enable debug on the daemon.

Comment: Thanks @user535733 I did check out your link and tried the procedure to use debug flag on he daemon. It did of course product debug info, but it was super high level and provided no clues. It basically only showed when the whole computer was restarted. I am looking for something that would indicate why the BT dongle would become unresponsive at a specific moment.